# Elasticsearch Grails query

Tags: java, grails, elasticsearch, lucene

I am trying multiple queries  in Elasticsearch to bring me back all the results for a given search string, be it a search phrase or an actual item indexed in Elasticsearch.

**Option 1: Global Index search** The below is what I am using for search but it doesn't seem to be working on bringing back search results for phrases

```
    def escaped =  QueryParser.escape(q.toLowerCase().trim())
    def result = elasticSearchService.search(escaped)
```

**Option 2 : Wildcard search** Also I tried the wildcard search which seem to work for phrases but when I key in a Elastic indexed item name, it returns back a blank result.

```
   def QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("name","*"+term.toLowerCase().trim()+"*")
   def result = elasticSearchService.search(qb)
```

Can someone help me with a universal query that can search all indexes for both given a phrase (return all results) and if given a specific indexed item name, return just the item name.

PS: I am using the elasticsearch-grails plugin to integrate the app with Elastic cluster

**Sample Document**

```
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "a.b.c.d",
        "_type": "svnInfo",
        "_id": "183",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "author": "abc1200",
           "name": "VendorSpec.groovy",
           "svnUrl": "http://svnrepo/tools/VendorSpec.groovy",
           "date": "Wed May 13 09:35:05 EDT 2015"
        }
     },
```

The above document with option 1 (global) when searched for "groovy" doesn't bring me back the VendorSpec.groovy

But the same document when explicity searched for "VendorSpec.groovy" with option 1, brings me back the document

**Domain class**

```
  class Svn {
    String name
    String author
    String date
    String svnUrl

    static  mapping = {
        id type:Long, sqlType:'INT'
        version false
    }

    static  constraints = {
        name(nullable:true,blank:true)
        svnUrl(nullable:true,blank:true)
        author(nullable:true,blank:true)
        date(nullable:true,blank:true)
    }

    static searchable = {
        name index:'analyzed'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some sample document you have which you think should match?

Comment: Sharing the document. I should have earlier